# I don't know how to implementate the function reduce

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mapreduce

I do not know how to implement the reduce function.
I have output from my map a document as ...
for example two documents
key "_id":"AD"
"values"
    {
            "numtweets" : 1,
            "hastags" : {
                    "OPINIÓ" : 1,
                    "debat" : 1,
                    "inexistent" : 1,
                    "tampoc" : 1,
                    "promet" : 1,
                    "gaire" : 1,
                    "diàleg" : 1
            }
    }
and other

```
{
        "numtweets" : 1,
        "hastags" : {
                "other" : 1,
                "debat" : 1,
                "inexistent" : 1,
                "another" : 1,
        }
}
```

I need a function that reduces all sum so that

```
"numtweets" : 2,
"dicwords" : {
        "OPINIÓ" : 1,
        "debat" : 2,
        "inexistent" : 2,
        "tampoc" : 1,
        "promet" : 1,
        "gaire" : 1,
        "diàleg" : 1,
        "other" : 1,
        "another" : 1
},
"lisuser" : {
        "user2" : 1
}
```

if my json values was only nuwtweets the reduce is

```
function(key, values) { 
  return Array.sum(values); 
};
```

if mi json values only was hastags (without numtweets and lisuser) the reduce function was

```
var r = function(key, values) { 
  result = {}
  values.forEach(function(val) {
    for (hashtag in val) {
      if (hashtag in result) {
        result[hashtag] = result[hashtag] + val[hashtag] 
      } else {
        result[hashtag] = val[hashtag] 
      }
    } 
  });
  return(result)
};
```

But I don't know how mix the 2 reduce function.
My level of mongodb and JavaScript is very low.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  let data = values.reduce((finalObj, ele) => {
  finalObj.numtweets += ele.numtweets
  for (key in ele.hastags) {
    if(ele.hastags.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(finalObj.hastags[key])
        finalObj.hastags[key] += ele.hastags[key]
      else
        finalObj.hastags[key] = ele.hastags[key]
    }
  }
  return finalObj
})
console.log(data)
```

Where values is array for objects which you want reduce to one object